# Symfony2 Entity Array

Tags: php, arrays, symfony

In my controller I have a function than set IP to entity:

```
$inventory = new Inventory();
$inventory->setIp($xml->COMPUTER->IP);
```

but `$xml->COMPUTER->IP` have two values. When I run:

```
foreach($xmlOcs->COMPUTER as $ips){
    echo $ips->IPADDRESS;
}
```

the two values are shown!

My question is, how can I set to entity (`$ip`) the two values?

My entity:

```
private $ipaddress = array(); 

public function setIpAddress($ipaddress) {
    $this->ipaddress = $ipaddress;

    return $this;
}

public function getIpAddress() {
    return $this->ipaddress;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please try to format this a bit better... Thanks =)

Comment: Your ORM configuration is missing from your entity. Your question is quite incomplete without it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your example, this can easily be done if you use array empty key assignment :

```
foreach($xmlOcs->COMPUTER as $ips){
    $inventory->addIpAddress($ips->IPADDRESS);
}


private $ipaddress = array(); 

public function addIpAddress($ipaddress) {
    $this->ipaddress[] = $ipaddress;

    return $this;
}

public function getIpAddress() {
    return $this->ipaddress;
}
```

However this has nothing to do with Symfony, it is pure very basic php.